# tinymce onPostProcess problem

Tags: plugins, tinymce

Here is html content from db

```
<p>Some p</p>
<p>some p 1</p>
<p><a href="http://www.google.com/">google</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.yahoo.com/">yahoo</a></p>

<p>{link class="readmore" cat_id="14" content_id="15" slug="Slug 1" content="Content 1"}</p>
<p>{link class="" cat_id="15" content_id="16" slug="Slug 2" content="Content 2"}</p>
<p>Some p 2 </p>
<p>Some p 3</p>
```

and then i use onBeforeSetContent function and convert html for tinymce like: No problem here...

```
<p>Some p</p> 
<p>some p 1</p> 
<p><a href="http://www.google.com/">google</a></p> <p><a href="http://www.yahoo.com/">yahoo</a></p> 
<p><a href="#" rel="SpecialLink" class="readmore" title="link class=&quot;readmore&quot; cat_id=&quot;14&quot; content_id=&quot;15&quot; slug=&quot;Slug 1&quot; content=&quot;Content 1&quot;">Content 1</a>
</p> 
<p><a href="#" rel="SpecialLink" class="" title="link class=&quot;&quot; cat_id=&quot;15&quot; content_id=&quot;16&quot; slug=&quot;Slug 2&quot; content=&quot;Content 2&quot;">Content 2</a></p> 
<p>Some p 2 </p> 
<p>Some p 3</p>
```

When the form is submitted i want to convert special urls to {link etc.} statement again with onPostProcess function. But it doesn't work. If i console.log(o.content) within onPostProcess content is same ; not converted and is beging saved to mysql wrong. But if console.log(t._get_link(o.content)) within onBeforeSetContent it works. I could not handle it for hours.

```
 ed.onBeforeSetContent.add(function(ed, o) {
            o.content = t._do_link(o.content);
        });

ed.onPostProcess.add(function(ed, o) {
            if (o.get)          
                o.content = t._get_link(o.content);
        });
```

below _do_link and _get_link functions;

```
_do_link :  function(co) {
        return co.replace(/\{link([^<]+)\}/g, function(a,b){

            content = b.match(/content=['"]([^'"]+)/i); 
            aclass =  b.match(/class=['"]([^'"]+)/i);

            if(aclass == undefined)
            {
                aclass = '';
            }
            else
            {
                aclass = aclass[1];
            }
            return '<a href="#" rel="SpecialLink" class="'+aclass+'" title="link'+tinymce.DOM.encode(b)+'">'+content[1]+'</a>';             
        });     
    },
    _get_link : function(co) {

        function getAttr(s, n) {
            n = new RegExp(n + '="([^"]+)"', 'g').exec(s);
            return n ? tinymce.DOM.decode(n[1]) : '';
        };

        return co.replace(/(<a href="([^"]+)" ([\S]*=.*(\ )*)*>([^<]+)<\/a>)/g, function(a,im) {

            var cls = getAttr(im, 'rel');

            if ( cls.indexOf('SpecialLink') != -1 )
            {
                return '{'+tinymce.trim(getAttr(im, 'title'))+'}';
            }
            return a;
        });
    }
```

Comment: i found the problem. But don't know how to solve it.
links should be:

<a href="#" rel="SpecialLink" title="link cat_id=&quot;14&quot; content_id=&quot;15&quot; slug=&quot;Slug 1&quot; content=&quot;Content 1&quot;">Content 1</a>

but its 
<a title="link cat_id=&quot;15&quot; content_id=&quot;16&quot; slug=&quot;Slug 2&quot; content=&quot;Content 2&quot;" href="#" rel="SpecialLink">Content 2</a>

why _do_link doesn't return string as is has to be?